# OpenGL and Java user interface architecture/comunication

Tags: opengl, java, rpg, gui

I'm working on the UIs for a turn based tactical rpg made with Java and LWJGL. 
I'd like to make a set of "dynamic" UIs similar to those of the game Torchlight 2. I would like to know if there are any good technique (or article) for build UI's architecture and regarding the comunication between UI and game (to handle, for example, events like button clicking).

Answer (score 3):

FengGUI is just such an implementation (Java GUI Framework on top of JOGL and LWJGL). You can get its sources [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fenggui/files/), maybe that will help you...